# I'm encountering a problem while executing 3 printf() statements

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    char v1,v2,v3;
    printf("enter: ");
    scanf("%c",&v1);
    printf("enter: ");
    scanf("%c",&v2);
    printf("enter: ");
    scanf("%c",&v3);
    
}
```

this is my sample code and I expect an output like:

```
enter: a
enter: b
enter: c
```

but I'm getting output like:

```
enter: a
enter: enter:
```

2nd and 3rd print statements are getting executed simultaneously.

Comment: Are you using one `printf` in each language?  The C# language may have different behavior than C or C++.

Comment: *"2nd and 3rd print statements are getting executed simultaneously."* -- I'd disagree with this assessment. If they were executed simultaneously, the second line of your output would look more like `enetnteerr: : ` (the two prompts intermixed). What you see is more likely the statements being executed sequentially, but without a pause in the middle. (No waiting on `scanf`.)

Comment: Are you mixing the three languages?  I highly recommend not mixing the three languages.  Mixing two of those three takes the program complexity up a couple of notches and makes debugging more difficult.  I recommend picking one of those three languages to write the program in.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. Pick one language and delete the tag for the other one.

Comment: A key piece of debugging information that should go with this question: what are the values of `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` at the end of your function? (I'd also recommend initializing them to some value to make it easier to see if their value had changed.)

Comment: The output you get seems to indicate IO error or EOF or something else strange. You should add code to check return value of `scanf`!

Comment: `scanf(" %c",&v1);` (note the addition of the `' '` (space) to read/discard any number of whitespace characters before reading the next character. (hint: `'\n'` that is left in `stdin` unread by the user pressing **Enter** -- is whtiespace) (do the same for your next two calls to `scanf()` as well...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're reading characters, so if what you enter is actually <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, that is actually SIX characters, and what you read will be the first 3 (the <kbd>a</kbd>, the <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the <kbd>b</kbd>)

What you can do is use a space in the scanf format to skip whitespace.  If you use `scanf(" %c", &v1);` then any whitespace (such as <kbd>Enter</kbd>) will be skipped, which will cause your result to be what you expect.  However, if someone enters something like <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, the program will seem to hang, waiting for non-whitespace to be entered

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in buffering. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer), which was already mentioned in the comments.

TL,DR: Use `scanf(" %c", &v);` to read chars, since it ignores all whitespace from the buffer, as well as the trailing newline.

Answer (score -1):

Hello what I would recommend is using a library that allows you to use a function called get_char.
I wrote a program using this function that does what you wanted yours to do.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cs50.h>
    
int main(void)
{
  char v1 = get_char("enter: ");
  char v2 = get_char("enter: ");
  char v3 = get_char("enter: ");
}
```

So the program stores 3 char values as they are entered one after another, without all executing at once. I don't know if this is the type of answer that you are looking for or if it will help you, but I figured I would put this out there. If its not really what your looking for let me know!

This is what the terminal looks like btw.:

```
$ make help
$ ./help
enter: a
enter: b
enter: c
```